# How to create a google search command in a discord bot?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am extremely new to Javascript and Discord.js, meaning that I copy most of my code online and try to understand them. I tried this google search command. However, my bot does not send anything. The only thing it sends is "Need Input" when I type .google. When I do input a search, it does not complete the task. It does not give me an error in my command prompt. Have I done something wrong? Do you have a completely different code? PS. My code is from https://github.com/OblivionSan/discord-googlebot/blob/master/commands/general/google.js

I have installed npm i google, but it sends me a lot of errors when I do.

```js
const google = require('google');
const Discord = require(`discord.js`);
exports.run = (client, message) => {
   if (!suffix) {
        message.channel.send({
            embed: {
                color: 0xff2727,
                description: `:warning: **${message.author.username}**, You didn't give me anything to search. {.google \`input\`}`,
            }
        });
    }
    google.resultsPerPage = 5;
    google(suffix, function (err, res) {
        if (err) message.channel.send({
            embed: {
                color: 0xff2727,
                description: `:warning: **${message.author.username}**, ${err}`,
                footer: {
                    text: 'API Lantancy is ' + `${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}` + ' ms',
                }
            }
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < res.links.length; ++i) {
            var link = res.links[i];
            if (!link.href) {
                res.next;
            } else {
                let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    .setColor(`#ffffff`)
                    .setAuthor(`Result for "${suffix}"`, `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/2000px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png`)
                    .setDescription(`**Link**: [${link.title}](${link.href})\n**Description**:\n${link.description}`)
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setFooter('API Lantancy is ' + `${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}` + ' ms', message.author.displayAvatarURL);
                return message.channel.send({
                    embed: embed
                });
            } return message.react("");
        }
    });
};
```

I expect a google search but get basically nothing. I get left on read :/

Comment: Question, has your bot successfully logged into discord? Are you able to capture what the user is sending? Looks like even if the suffix isn't set, your bot will try to search google anyways.

Comment: Scraping Google's Web Pages is against their ToS; I recommend not to do it.

Answer (score 2):

That module is not working as of now, as far as I can tell. I'm using the GoogleIt module for [my bot](https://github.com/ConnorAhern/search-bot), and here's the code that I'm using for a sample:

```
const googleIt = require('google-it')
const Discord = require(`discord.js`);

exports.run = (bot, message, args) => {
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle("Google Search Results")
        .setColor(3426654)
        .setTimestamp()
            

    googleIt({'query': args.join(' ')}).then(results => {
        results.forEach(function(item, index) { 
            embed.addField((index + 1) + ": " + item.title, "<" + item.link + ">");
        });
        
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }).catch(e => {
        // any possible errors that might have occurred (like no Internet connection)
    });
};

module.exports.help = {
    name: 'google',
    aliases: []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check what I have below and see if that works. I usually use an object for the embed. You can generate / see one here => https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/ when you click the generate button and select discord.js

```js
// this config option doesn't really need to be in your method / function
google.resultsPerPage = 5;

client.on('message', (message) => {
  // Using !search as a suffix in a regex
  if (/!search/.test(message.content))) {
    // remove the suffix
    const search = message.content.replace('!search ', '');

    google('node.js best practices', (err, res) => {
      if (err) console.error(err)

      for (var i = 0; i < res.links.length; ++i) {
        var link = res.links[i];

        // At this point, you should see your data and just have to format your embed
        console.log(link.title + ' - ' + link.href)
        console.log(link.description + "\n")
      }
    }
  }
});
```